# error occuring due to 2 controls - spinner & radioButton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

when extending AppCompatActivity it will be error in Spinner?
Could not find class 'android.widget.ThemedSpinnerAdapter', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner$DropDownAdapter.

When Extending Activity It will be error in radioButton?
inflate expection in binary xml file

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.dipali.hindujodidar/com.example.dipali.hindujodidar.activity.ActivityRegisterOtherDetails}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.RadioButton

**XML Layout File**

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="Other Details"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/heading"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:src="@mipmap/heading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtHeightInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtHeightInFeet"
            android:hint="Height In Feet"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtComplexionInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtComplexion"
            android:hint="Complexion"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edt"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSpectacle"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Spectacle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgSpectacle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbSpectacleYes"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbSpectacleNO"
            android:text="No"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPhysicalDisability"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Physical Disability"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgPhysicalDisability"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbPhysicaDisabilityYes"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
                android:text="Yes"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_width="155dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbPhysicalDisabilityNO"
                android:text="No"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtHobbiesInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtHobbies"
        android:hint="Hobbies"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spRashi"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
</LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNRI"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
        android:text="NRI"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgNRI"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNRIYes"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNRINo"
            android:text="No"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spBloodGroup"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spCaste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/spinner"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spMaritalStatus"
        android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtExpectionInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtExceptions"
        android:lines="4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edt"
        android:hint="Expectations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtValidation2"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="#ef0c0c"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSecondNext"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btntxt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you add your xml layout and if any, styles references?